# Omniauth and changing passwords

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I just got my project working where users can log in/ sign up through facebook as well as the native login. Everything is working perfectly, but the only issue is that I can't figure out how to allow users to update their passwords... because, well, how do you put in your existing password when you never used one in the first place?

Any ideas how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a link that sends them an email with a token in it, the same way you would implement a forgotten password.